# C++ Error: Cannot convert 'Object' to 'Object*'

Tags: c++

I'm trying to compile my code, the compiler spits out it cannot convert `Connection` to `Connection*` but in the function argument I never specified a pointer as an argument.

Header declaration

I found my problem. Sorry guys

```
QueryResult execute_select(Connection *db, QString query);
```

Source

```cpp
QueryResult execute_select(Connection db, QString query)
{
    int rc;
    char* error_message = 0;
    QueryResult rs;
    //----------Convert Qstring to char
    char* sql = (char*) query.toStdString().c_str();

    rc = sqlite3_exec(db.db, sql, &callback, (void*) &rs, &error_message);

    #ifdef QT_DEBUG
    if(rc != SQLITE_OK){

    }

    #endif

    sqlite3_close(db.db);


    return rs;
}
```

Where the compiler error occurs:

**EDIT:** 
This is the get connection method, it doesn't return a pointer

```
Connection get_database_connection(char* d_path)
{
    Connection conn;
    sqlite3 *db;

    //Open db
    int rc = sqlite3_open(d_path, &db);
    //Check if db is open
    if(rc != SQLITE_OK){
        conn.status = CONNECTION_FAILED;
        return conn;
    }

    conn.db = db;
    conn.path = (char*) db_path.toStdString().c_str();
    conn.status = CONNECTION_SUCCESS;

    return conn;

}
```

```
Connection conn = get_database_connection(converted_path);
//Compiler error
QueryResult rs = execute_select(conn, query_string);
```

Compiler message:

> Data\accounts.cpp: In member function 'std::list* Accounts::load()':
>   Data\accounts.cpp:29:55: error: cannot convert 'Connection' to 'Connection*' for argument '1' to 'QueryResult execute_select(Connection
>   *, QString)'
>        QueryResult rs = execute_select(conn, query_string);

I expected the code to compile, but its not.

Comment: `get_database_connection(converted_path);` returns a `Connection*` pointer, not a `Connection`.

Comment: `char* sql = (char*) query.toStdString().c_str();` is a trap. You get a pointer to the data of an `std::string` that's returned by `toStdString()` but that string is a temporary object and ceases to exist at the end of the expression. By the time you try to use the pointer it's no longer valid. Edit : Not to mention casting away the `const`, which is definitely a bad idea.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using the builtin sqlite support in Qt?

Comment: Is `execute_select(...)` declared in a separate header file? Maybe, you have a pointer type argument there? So, I'd start by commenting out `execute_select(...)` implementation (the one you posted in the question) and seeing if that changes the error.

Comment: I don't think enough code is posted. is this your own sqlite wrapper? Or is it some opensource code? Also this error `error: cannot convert 'Connection' to 'Connection*' for argument '1' to 'QueryResult execute_select(Connection
*, QString)'` tells me that `execute_select()` expects a `Connection*` for the first argument but you are giving it a `Connection` instead.

Comment: "i never specified a pointer as an argument." Perhaps someone else did without your knowledge. The compiler sees the pointer there, because it's in the error message. Little else can be said until you can show a [mcve].

Comment: @Dmitry may be correct in that the problem is in the header. We can't tell because that information is not in the question.

Comment: Please post the header that declares `execute_select()`

Comment: `conn.path = (char*) db_path.toStdString().c_str();` most likely won't work. However its unrelated to the other problem.

Comment: @Dmitry tried it, doesnt seem to work

Comment: @drescherjm just learning sqlite, i thought i'd design my own wrapper

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Already updated the get_database_connection(converted_path); doesnt return a Connection pointer

Comment: @Teddy In the question, you provide the header declaration of "execute_update" while you should provide "execute_select"

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé ops sorry my bad

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé thanks i found the problem. I was looking a the wrong function. My problem is now solved

Comment: @Teddy Glad to hear it! Please put your solution as an answer so the question can be "closed".

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé, done you can close the question

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, I have little experience. So how should i go about it?

Comment: @Teddy It seems like `conn::path` is a `char*` which makes it very hard to use correctly. If you control the `Connection` class, consider changing it's `path` member to `std::string` instead.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux but i've used `char*` for my sqlite wrapper functions. It works though, and i don't want to touch it.

Comment: @Teddy "It works so I won't touch it" is a very dangerous approach. Assuming there is actually an error (there is in this case) it actually means "It works *for now* so I won't touch it". Inevitable it will eventually break, usually in a long time when you won't even remember having written this. At that point, you'll likely have no idea *what* broke, you won't suspect it's something that's been working for a while. `conn.path = (char*) db_path.toStdString().c_str();` is 100% incorrect for many reasons and I guarantee it will break at some point. It will be harder to fix later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've guessed in comments, the problem was in function declaration (and you was looking at function definition/implementation). Posting this again just so you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at the execute_update(Connection db, QString query); declaration.
The execute_select(Connection *db, QString query); was at the bottom of the file.It was somehow invisible to my eyes. I changed the pointer declaration. The code compiles.